# Show that $M\in [AC] $ or $M\in [BD] $.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

Let $ABCD $ a rombhus and $M $ an interior point. If $\angle AMB+ \angle CMD=180^{\circ}$.

Show that $M\in [AC] $ or $M\in [BD] $.

I tried to solve it with sine and cosine but I didn't succed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $NBCM$ be parallelogram.

Thus, $NBMA$ is cyclic, which says $$\measuredangle BAM=\measuredangle BNM=\measuredangle BCM,$$
which says $$\measuredangle CAM=\measuredangle ACM,$$ which gives $$AM=MC,$$
which says $$M\in BD.$$

All this if $M\not\in AC$.

If $M\in AC$ then we are done again.

Comment: Can you draw the picture?

Comment: I found a typo and fixed it. See now.

Comment: Why is AMBN cyclic? Why$m (\angle AMB)+m (\angle ANB)=180?$

Comment: Because $\Delta ANB\cong\Delta DMC$.